# .htaccess - Removing of .php works, but leads to 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm working on an API system with PHP, but I don't want the URLs to contain the file extension. Therefore, I've created a .htaccess file containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://xxxxx.com/api/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://xxxxx.com/api/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

When opening http://xxxxx.com/api/some_call.php, it redirects me to http://xxxxx.com/api/some_call, but I get a 404 not found error:

```
The requested URL /api/some_call was not found on this server.
```

I have full control over the (root) server, so any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance,

CrushedPixel

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the conditions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

And try and add `Options -Multiviews` above the `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: The actual solution was removing the `Options -Multiviews` part from my apache config.